# Parsing serial data in Python via USB interface

Tags: python, parsing, serial-port

This is the code for reading data from serial port and also parsing. The serial port sends alarm as the alarm generates it sends it to the RS-232 port (Serial communication):

```
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS, timeout=None, xonxoff=1)

while True:
    rcv=[]
    beta=[]

    rcv = port.readline()
    rcv=rcv.decode("UTF-8")
    beta = (rcv)
    replacements = (' ',' ','/','\r','\n')
    for r in replacements:
        beta = beta.replace(r,' ')

    #beta = beta.split()

    print(beta)
```

Output:

```
!!! *A0628 306  18-04-20 19 H 45 N=5373 TYP=COM CAT=IM EVENT=MAL  
     NCEN=QTCEN  AFCN =CNLM12-0 AGEO=S1-TR01-B14-A003  
     TEXAL=CN ISOLATED
```

The main problem is that is that i am unable to parse all these values.
I want this:

```
A = !!! <br>
B = *A0628<br>
C = 306<br>
D = 18-04-20<br>
E = 19 H 45
```

and so on till all the values covered.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Newbie here thanks for the edit and please help to solve this problem if you know rather than finding mistakes ... @halfer